# How to send a ping once a minute to Server in a RELIABLE manner?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-6.0-marshmallow

In my Android application I need to send a message to the server (basically a ping) once a minute when a certain feature is activated. The feature may be activated for 2-3 hours, so it's important that the ping is sent continuously and in a timely fashion.

To achieve this I am currently using AsyncTasks (for sending the request), launched once a minute via a foreground Service, which is scheduled with alarmManagers' setExactAndAllowWhileIdle. The foreground service does have a partial wakelock too!

Unfortunately it looks like Marshmallow's doze mode ends up swallowing the alarms at some random point. This happens EVERY TIME and at arbitrary points. Sometimes the app sends pings for 2 hours without problems, sometimes only for 30 minutes, before they don't go off anymore (and then restarting 10-15 minutes later).

What can I do to get the ping sent continuously? It is incredibly important for the app. The only other alternative I can see is that I use the GCM to send high-priority messages every 5 minutes or so to keep it alive, but I that would be a terrible hack.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the user to add your app to the battery optimization whitelist.

Or, ask the user to only use this feature when connected to a charger or external battery pack.

Or, ask the user to jiggle their device every few minutes for a few moments, to try to convince Android that it is not sitting idle on a nightstand.

Or, build your own custom ROM, where you take steps to modify Android to allow your app to consume arbitrary amounts of power, then have users install your custom ROM.

Note that AFAIK your GCM solution would need to be every minute, not every five minutes, if you want to send "pings" every minute. The GCM solution does not prevent the device from going into Doze mode; it merely allows you to send messages to the app and have a brief window of connectivity. It is possible that the window is 5+ minutes, but I wouldn't count on it.

Note that you are saying, in effect, that the CPU will need to be on **continuously** for your 2-3 hour window, due to your partial `WakeLock`. You are also saying that some radio (WiFi or cellular) will be in a high-power mode for much of that time as well, since they go through a series of power states with relatively slow transition times, and an every-minute set of packets will push the radio back into the high-power state. What you are doing is exceptionally bad for battery life.

If your users agree that what you are doing is "incredibly important" **to them**, they will not mind adding you to the whitelist, or only using this feature while on a charger.

Comment: Adding the app to the optimization whitelist will not help, as you will not get more that one wakeup in 9 minutes.